# What is the most generic way to allocate a cv::Mat object?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have some allocated `cv::Mat face;` with actual data in it and I want to perform something along the lines of the following:

```
cv::Mat gray_image;
cv::Mat x_gradient_image;
cv::Mat temp;

cv::cvtColor(face, gray_image, CV_RGB2GRAY);
cv::Sobel(gray_image, temp, 1, 1, 0); 
cv::convertScaleAbs(temp, x_gradient_image, 1, 0);
```

This causes the program to crash, but I assumed in the new C++ API that `cv::Mat` objects were good at allocating their own memory.  What is the simplest way to allocate the memory for those `cv::Mat` objects?

Comment: I don't think the crash is due to allocation. It's probably invalid input to the Sobel function. At least that's what happens when I run your code: `OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (Unsupported combination of buffer format (=5), and destination format (=1)) in getLinearColumnFilter, file /Users/steve/Development/opencv2/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/filter.cpp, line 2674`

Comment: Actually, you're right.  The wrong depth is given.  Replaced the depth parameter of the sobel operation and we're good.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the depth parameter in the call to Sobel and your code worked for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    cv::Mat face;
    // read an image
    if (argc < 2)
        face = cv::imread("../../IMG_0080.jpg");
    else
        face = cv::imread(argv[1]);

    if (!face.data) {
        std::cout << "Image file not found\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cv::Mat gray_image;
    cv::Mat x_gradient_image;
    cv::Mat temp;

    cv::cvtColor(face, gray_image, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    cv::Sobel(gray_image, temp, 5, 1, 0); 
    cv::convertScaleAbs(temp, x_gradient_image, 1, 0);

    // show the image in a window
    cv::imshow("so8044872", x_gradient_image);
    // wait for key
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```